# Number of solutions to the equation $ x_{1} + ... + x_{k} = 100$ as a function of k?

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone help me understand why, calling **n** to the number of possible solutions to the below equation and constraint:
$$
x_{1} + ... + x_{k} = 100 ;\textit{ }x_{i}\geq 1 \textit{ for }1 \leq i \leq k
$$
**n** is:
$$
n= \binom{99}{k-1}
$$

It is used in my text book to reach the solution of a broader problem, but I can't see exactly why n takes that value.

Thank you!

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @RR_28023 You may want to mention that $x_i$ are integers.